# What are CSRF attacks and how to prevent it?

Tags: php, csrf

Recently I have read about CSRF attacks on websites. I want know more about CSRF attacks on websites and its prevention methods. Help me to find out more about this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: you should google and you find a lot of blog, post and article

Comment: This is a question you should ask google. This is a massive topic.

Comment: May I suggest you use a search engine, try CSRF. OWASP is a good resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF stands for Cross Site Request Forgery. I'll explain with an example.

Consider you have built a form for users to fill in on your website. What if the same form is copied by miscreants and used on their website? How would you know the form that is submitted is the legitimate one and submitted from your own website? This is called CSRF. There are few methods that can be used to prevent such forgeries. You may find some solutions here:

https://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Cross-Site-Request-Forgery-(CSRF)-Attacks-in-PHP

Comment: You are welcome.